# What is the Laplacian mask/kernel used in the scipy.ndimage.filter.laplace()?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, filter, scipy

A simple horizontal/vertical Laplace mask has 4 in the center of the kernel (left side of the figure).  Similarly, a Laplace mask sensitive to diagonal features has 8 in the center of the kernel (right side in the figure bellow). What mask is `scipy` using, and can I choose which one to use?

[image]

Comment: It seems MATLAB uses the `4` based kernel, so maybe the same for scipy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A simple check would be to declare a 2D array of zeroes except for one coefficient in the centre which is set to 1, then apply the `laplace` function to it.  A property with filtering is that if you submit an image with a single 1, the output would be the actual filter itself centered at the location of where the 1 is - look up [impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response)... or more specifically, the [Point Spread Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function).

If you do this, then you'll see what it looks like after you run through the `laplace` method:

```
In [13]: import numpy as np

In [14]: import scipy.ndimage.filters

In [15]: A = np.zeros((5,5))

In [16]: A[2,2] = 1

In [17]: B = scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace(A)

In [18]: A
Out[18]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [19]: B
Out[19]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1., -4.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

As such, it's the first kernel that is being used, but note the sign change.  The centre coefficient is positive while the others are negative.

---

However, if you really want to know what's going on underneath the hood, check out the docs on the function: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace.html - There's a link to the source of where the function is defined:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.0/scipy/ndimage/filters.py#L396

The relevant code you need to look at is here:

```
def derivative2(input, axis, output, mode, cval):
    return correlate1d(input, [1, -2, 1], axis, output, mode, cval, 0)
return generic_laplace(input, derivative2, output, mode, cval)
```

Basically, a 1D kernel of `[1, -2, 1]` is being applied to each dimension independently as done by the `correlate1d` function... so the rows first, followed by the columns.  This in effect computes the first mask that you see in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. 
How can I suggest to Scipy community to offer the user the freedom to choose from the two mask options?

Comment: @Arcticpython - Glad I could help!  The best way is to raise an issue on Github.  https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/ - Raise a new issue and ask if it's possible to specify different types of the Laplacian as one mask is used over another in certain situations.  Make sure you specify where the relevant code is that will be affected... so the link I gave you above that links to the Github repo where `laplace` is defined is a start.